# How to find Booking without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to destroy a column of my Booking table.

I have an index of the join table in courses_controller.rb like this:

```
@bookings = Booking.joins(:schedule).where(user_id: current_user.id).where("schedules.status_id = ?", 11).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

and in the view:

```
         <% @bookings.each.with_index(1) do |b, index| %>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <small><%= index %></small>
              </th>
              <td>
                <small><%= b.schedule.available.strftime("%b %e, %I:%M %p") %></small>
              </td>
              <td>
                <small></small>
              </td>
              <td>
                <small><%= b.schedule.tutor.name %></small>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning text-white text-capitalize">
                  <%= b.schedule.status.name %>
                </span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to "Cancel request", users_bookings_path(b), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-light btn-sm text-color-3 border" %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
```

In the booking_controller.rb, I have method to destroy:

```
class Users::BookingsController < ApplicationUserController
before_action :find_request, only: :destroy

def destroy
 @request.destroy
 flash[:info] = "Success cancel request"
 redirect_to users_requested_classes_path
end

private
def booking_params
 params.permit(:user_id, :status_id, :schedule_id)
end

def find_request
 @request = Booking.find(params[:id])
end


end
```

and my routes:

```
resource :bookings, only: :destroy
```

This is the web server console log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPZ3U.png)

When I click the cancel request button, it shows "Couldn't find Booking without an ID." Why?

Comment: Please show the entire web server console log from when it receives the request until the error. We need to see your params, etc.

Comment: done. i've updated on the post @Beartech

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]", especially the part about "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!". SO isn't a message board or forum, it's more like an online reference book where grammar matters. "i" => "I", `shows Couldn't find... ID` => `shows "Couldn't find... ID"`. The time we spend editing takes away from the time we have to help answer questions. Also, please read "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in your logs it is asking for:

```
users/bookings.4
```

And in your parameters below that it shows the only parameter as the authenticity token? It should also have an ID param. The reason is you are using the wrong path helper in your form.

```
<%= link_to "Cancel request", users_bookings_path(b), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-light btn-sm text-color-3 border" %>
```

generates

```
users/bookings.4
```

but if you use `users_booking_path(b)` like:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel request", users_booking_path(b), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-light btn-sm text-color-3 border" %>
```

It should generate the correct path like:

```
users/bookings/4
```

Comment: Always read your server logs, they will usually tell you what the problem is. You have to really look for things that not look normal.

Comment: Paths and plural/singular can get complicated, especially if english is not your first language. I would run a `rake routes` to get a listing of all of your routes and it will show you which ones refer to single resources, etc.

Comment: yeah.. thank you for your help. really appreciate, actually its my routes that has problem. thanks again bro